# Gilbert-Peierls algorithm for LU Decomposition

Tags: algorithms, matlab, matrix

I searched for Gilbert-Peierls algorithm, but I haven't found anything useful (well, I found [this](http://sugandima.wikia.com/wiki/Methods_of_solving_Ax=b_and_their_Matlab_implementations), but it's not working as it should). I think the problem is the second part, and also that those lines:

```
U(1:k, k) = x(1:k);
L(k:N, k) = x(k:N)/U(k, k);
```

should actually be (according to [this](http://sugandima.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aGilbert-Peierls_algorithm_for_LU_Decomposition) example):

```
U(1:N, k) = x(1:N);
L(k:N, k) = x(k:N)/U(k, k);
```

Also, in that example, L is the identity matrix, which I find a bit strange. Could someone describe the algorithm, please? (with or without code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check this out:
http://cci.lbl.gov/cctbx_sources/scitbx/sparse/lu_factorization.h